# Plotting on maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I am﻿ making an application where I get an message with latitude and longitude, I search that and then plot it on google maps.
How to accomplish the plotting ??

Comment: You may want to edit your question and put relevant code you have already.

Comment: In the question you mention you want to know how to perform plotting on the map, yet on my answer you mention you want to know how to parse a lat/lng from a String. Please re-phrase your question, and add what you already tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

If by "plotting on the map" you mean adding a marker (icon) to a map at a given Latitude / Longitude, you can use the following code to put a Marker on Sydney on the map :

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(-33.88,151.21))
        .title("Hello world"));
```

The LatLng object accepts 2 doubles representing a latitude and a longitude in degrees.

[The Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) is pretty well-documented. There's also a [guide on Markers in Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker)

Comment: this above code is hardcoded and only those locations will be shown with the balloon. but i need to plot external lat long which i get through message

Comment: please explain a bit better what you want to achieve. What is your input and output ?

Comment: The google map application receives a text message. The message contains set of string and latitude and longitude of a place. What i want my application to do is it searches the lat and long values using a search java code and immediate after that i want those to be plotted on a google map saying balloon-A/or marker(wt ever)..then sequence of such message arrives from different location and they should be similarly plotted on  map.

Comment: What do you mean by "searches the lat and long values using a search java code". The code in answer shows you how to plot a marker with an InfoWindow for a given lat/lng. (replace 0,0 with whatever you get in your text message). Do you need help receiving the text message, parsing the text message, do you want to lookup an address/place for the given lat/lng ?

Comment: I receive text message. but how to fit the lat long values in the code above. i might need help in parsing once the lat long values from the message is searched.

Comment: Don't know what else to say... if you have a reference to your latitude / longitude as a string, convert them to doubles and store them in a LatLng as illustrated in the code.

Comment: @ ddewaele - any suitable search code to search the lat and long values. the string format might be like this "# Lat= 3456.677675544 Long= 344.098765657"